# Looping program freezes due to memory running out

Tags: python, loops, ubuntu

I am running the same stochastic program 100,000 times using:
Loop 100000
None of the data is stored after each loop

After about 30,000 loops the program freezes, I assume through lack of memory. Is there anything I can put at the start of each loop to clean memory?

I am running a Python program using Ubuntu on a Dell laptop.

Thanks in advance

at the start of each loop all files are cleared, such as:

del resistance[:]

Comment: Can you post the actual program? It's possible that there's something you're missing that we might be able to find.

Comment: pip install psutil, print the following each loop; dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())   -- verify that indeed your memory is decreasing.

Comment: I'd recommend against explicitly deleting names like in `del resistance[:]`, but be aware that the name `resistance` will still exist after that operation, it will just be blank. It's possible that you're filling up your memory with references to empty objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you specifically, but it is good for freeing up memory.  Try importing `gc` and call `gc.collect()` right before and/or inside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I tried installing psutil, it installed in Unix but when I went to run it in Python it said psutil was not installed. Other people seem to get the same problem. I am running with gc.collect() and waiting to see what happens.

A question for silver. Why does Python keep allocating storage when I run del resistance[ : ]? as in:

Loops = 30000
for i range(Loops):
   del resistance[ : ];
     for j in range(15):
       resistance[] = some_function;